# How to relation with two table when column value is a array in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I need all reports with all officers included in the participants column.

please check the attached image.

https://prnt.sc/CRoELD48J-L5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really have a `participant` pivot table with `report_id` and `officer_id`, and create proper relationships.

What you're asking for is possible through loops and lazy loading, but it will be extremely slow and unoptimized.